# Import error on first-party library with dev_appserver.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine

On Ubuntu 16.04, am suddenly getting import errors from the local GAE development server.

The local dev server starts up, including the admin interface, but app no longer loads.

Native python imports of the same library on same machine (in this case "from google.cloud import datastore") work fine.

The GAE standard app does run when deployed, but development just got a little challenging.

google-cloud is version 0.27.0
gcloud components is 172.0.1
python is Anaconda 2.7.13
GAE is standard

I have confirmed to the best of my middling abilities that $PATH is correct for all named libraries.

I have removed and re-added all the named libraries to no effect.

cachetools(2.0.1) it should probably be noted, is installed as a dependency of the google cloud libraries, so I don't think this is addressable through requirements.txt or "libraries" in app.yaml.

I did recently go through a cycle of removing and adding libraries to fix a problem with apache_beam 2.0.1, so I may have jacked up something else, but am not sure where to look.

Suggestions deeply appreciated. Full traceback (from admin, same as from app):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime/request_handler.py", line 232, in handle_interactive_request
    exec(compiled_code, self._command_globals)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/brian/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from google.cloud.datastore.client import Client
  File "/home/brian/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/datastore/client.py", line 23, in <module>
    from google.cloud.client import ClientWithProject
  File "/home/brian/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/client.py", line 27, in <module>
    from google.oauth2 import service_account
  File "/home/brian/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/oauth2/service_account.py", line 79, in <module>
    from google.auth import jwt
  File "/home/brian/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/auth/jwt.py", line 49, in <module>
    import cachetools
ImportError: No module named cachetools
```

Comment: Looks like `cachetools` is not installed. Have you tried to reinstall it?

Comment: Yes, cachetools is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I addressed my problem through the requirements.txt file in app root directory.

I had: google-cloud==0.22.0

and changed it to: google-cloud==0.27.0

which fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace indicates you're running the libraries from the local system installation (the `site-packages` dir), not from your app.

For standard env GAE apps you need to install the dependencies *inside your app* and they will be uploaded to GAE together with your app code.

More specifically you need to use the `-t <your_app_lib_dir>` option for the `pip` installation. From [Installing a third-party library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library):

> 2. Use [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) (version 6 or later) with the `-t <directory>` flag to copy the libraries into the folder you created in the previous
>      step. For example:
>
>    ```
>    pip install -t lib/ <library_name>
>    ```

Comment: Dan thanks.  I think my error is a bit different, as the cachetools dependency is from the native google cloud import, so not purely a third-party issue.

Comment: I did, however, try your suggestion, and got other import errors.  Direct-from-dev_appserver.py stack trace is...

Comment: too long for comments.

Comment: But the crux is: File "/home/brian/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime/sandbox.py", line 1091, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named _ctypes