# Cannot import six on GAE local development environment

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I got below error when trying to run my GAE Python 2.7 app.

```
ImportError: No module named six
```

I have followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27) page and set up my `app.yaml` file like below.

```
...
libraries:
  - name: six
    version: "1.9.0"
  - name: flask
    version:  "0.12"
  - name: jinja2
    version: "2.6"
  - name: pycrypto
    version: "2.6.1"
  - name: markupsafe
    version: "0.23"
  - name: werkzeug
    version: "0.11.10"
  - name: pytz
    version: "2017.3"
```

I first got this error when I try to import the `flask` package. So I wrote some debug code to investigate this issue, and I found I cannot import `six` directly either.

I printed out the `sys.path` variable.

```
['C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\gaeapp\\dist', 'C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\gaeapp\\dist\\lib', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\envs\\py27-base\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\envs\\py27-base\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\envs\\py27-base', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\lib\\flask-0.12', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\lib\\jinja2-2.6', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\lib\\pycrypto-2.6.1', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\lib\\markupsafe-0.23', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\lib\\werkzeug-0.11.10', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\lib\\pytz-2017.3', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\lib\\six-1.9.0', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\lib\\click-6.6', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\lib\\itsdangerous-0.24', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\lib\\setuptools-0.6c11', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\lib\\protorpc-1.0', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\lib\\webapp2-2.3', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\lib\\webob-1.1.1', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\lib\\yaml-3.10']
```

I also checked that *C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\six-1.9.0* exist.

I also tried to import the `six` package directly in a python shell, and it succeeded.

```
(py27-base) C:\>set PYTHONPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\six-1.9.0

(py27-base) C:\>python
Python 2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Nov 13 2018, 17:33:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import six
>>> six
<module 'six' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\six-1.9.0\six\__init__.py'>
>>> exit()
```

So I wonder what prevented my app from importing `six` within the **dev_appserver** environment.

### Environment Detail

- Windows 10 64 bit, build 1809
- Python 2.7.15 :: Anaconda, Inc.
- GAE Python Standard SDK, version 1.9.80. **Not GCloud SDK**

### Log Detail

```
2018-12-19 14:00:18 Running command: "['C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\envs\\py27-base\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=8080', '--admin_port=8000', 'C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\gaeapp\\dist']"
INFO     2018-12-19 14:00:22,907 devappserver2.py:278] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2018-12-19 14:00:23,483 api_server.py:275] Starting API server at: http://localhost:54700
INFO     2018-12-19 14:00:23,493 dispatcher.py:256] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2018-12-19 14:00:23,497 admin_server.py:150] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
INFO     2018-12-19 14:00:28,579 instance.py:294] Instance PID: 11908
INFO     2018-12-19 14:00:30,862 module.py:861] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO     2018-12-19 14:00:35,223 module.py:434] [default] Detected file changes:
  blog\__init__.pyc
WARNING  2018-12-19 06:00:35,575 sandbox.py:1086] The module _winreg is whitelisted for local dev only. If your application relies on _winreg, it is likely that it will not function properly in production.

WARNING  2018-12-19 06:00:35,953 sandbox.py:1086] The module _ctypes is whitelisted for local dev only. If your application relies on _ctypes, it is likely that it will not function properly in production.

WARNING  2018-12-19 06:00:36,165 sandbox.py:1086] The module msvcrt is whitelisted for local dev only. If your application relies on msvcrt, it is likely that it will not function properly in production.

ERROR    2018-12-19 06:00:36,315 wsgi.py:263] 

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle

handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler

handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject

obj = __import__(path[0])

  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\gaeapp\dist\blog\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>

from blog.resources import bloglist, blog, comment

  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\gaeapp\dist\blog\resources\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>

from flask_restful import fields

  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\gaeapp\dist\lib\flask_restful\fields.py", line 6, in <module>

import six

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\runtime\sandbox.py", line 1149, in load_module

raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)

ImportError: No module named six

INFO     2018-12-19 14:00:36,362 module.py:861] default: "GET /blog/resources/blogs HTTP/1.1" 500 -
INFO     2018-12-19 14:00:41,301 instance.py:294] Instance PID: 19088
INFO     2018-12-19 14:00:41,301 module.py:434] [default] Detected file changes:
  blog
```

Comment: @DanCornilescu, thanks for pointing out. Actually, the indentation was correct in my code. But somehow messed up in the post.

Comment: Can you show the full traceback? Are you using the GAE or the Cloud SDK? You appear to be running the devserver via Pycharm - can you also try to run it from a shell - just in case it's a pycharm config issue? Maybe show exactly how you're running the devserver (I mean the command line).

Comment: In addition to Dan's questions above, what version of the Cloud SDK are you running? You can find that by running the command `gcloud component list`.

Comment: Added more detail in the post. @DanCornilescu, I observed this error when running in PyCharm, and reproduced it using the GAE Launcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a test environment as per your description above, but didn’t run into issues when importing the modules you specified in the `app.yaml` file. Another possible troubleshooting would be to create a demo app in order to double-check if the GAE Launcher is able to fetch those built-in libraries within the dev_appserver environment. To that end, by going in the Google App Engine Launcher, `File > Add Demo Application > python > guestbook` and editing both the `app.yaml` and `guestbook.py` file to import (for instance) the `six` module and print `var = six.__version__` in the Guestbook page, you would be able to check if an exception is raised.

A possible solution, as suggested by Alex, would be to directly copy the third-party libraries locally to a (sub)directory by adding them to a `requirements.txt` file, running `pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt` and creating a corresponding `appengine_config.py` file, as outlined in [this article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library). Keep in mind, though, that by only importing the libraries to the ‘Development’ environment, the issue could still show up in Production, in which case having the `appengine_config.py` file as:

```
# appengine_config.py
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# Add any libraries install in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add('lib')
```

would be ideal (as seen on the article provided in Alex’s response).

I would also add that if the project has other local libraries as well (which seems to be the case from the traceback), make sure to install those dependencies *inside* your app, as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46409539/10802003).

Comment: Actually, I deleted everything in my `lib` directory, reinstalled all the packages then deleted the packages included in the runtime. This time, everything works. I think the real solution is just to reinstall the packages...

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced issues with random libraries that are present in production being absent in my localhost (namely pycrypto on osx)

So, in addition to having a `lib` folder for all my third party libs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27

I set up a second folder called `localhost_libs` for these problematic libraries

and then in my `appengine_config.py` I have this:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add('lib')

if os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Development'):
    vendor.add('localhost_libs')
```

Comment: According to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#using_a_built-in_third-party_library_bundled_with_the_runtime, *pycrypto* is only included in production, not in the SDK package.